# How can I determine the height in this fluid dynamics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Here's the problem:
[image: Problem 2]

I used Bernoulli's Equation and tried to make the height the subject:

[image: problem soln]
The tricky thing about the problem is that the initial height is not given. Checking by dimensional analysis also shows that the equation I came up with is incorrect. How can I determine the height?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: At least I showed that I made an attempt on the question.

Comment: Well, you wrote some stuff down on a piece of paper and took a picture of it.  You didn't think too hard about what the question asked, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the proper Bernoulli equation for this problem, then you went on a cancellation frenzy with the pg terms which was incorrect, after properly neglecting any change in flow velocity.

Delta P / (pg) = Delta h is what you should have left in your Bernoulli equation after neglecting the change in velocity.

Since the problem is looking only for the change in height of the pipe to produce the required increase in pressure, you can set h1 = 0 or some other convenient number.  After that, finding h2 is how you say, trivial.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  If you are going to solve a problem like this, you gotta get the algebra right.